# Table View Unknown Shadow Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a table view in my app that I have set up to switch between two different viewing modes. When a button is pressed, the table view changes to display completed tasks rather than tasks needing attention. Toggling this works as expected, until you mark a task complete or incomplete. After this, the next time the user presses the show complete tasks button, it will crash the app giving this error:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _addPendingSwipeDeletionShadowUpdateForSection:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3688.4/UITableView.m:15334
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal inconsistency: the _swipedIndexPath cannot be nil when adding the shadow update'

I know the error says something about a shadow and swiped index path, but I have not messed with the shadows of the table view, so I am not sure what the problem is, especially since this worked fine a few days ago. My code for switching between complete and incomplete data is this:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
if showComplete {
    showComplete = false
    if completedArray.count != 0 {
        tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
    }
    if taskArray.count != 0 {
        allComplete()
    }
    else {
        tasksIncomplete()
        tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet.init(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(0, taskArray.count)) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
    }            
}
else {
    showComplete = true
    if taskArray.count != 0 {
        tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet.init(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(0, taskArray.count)) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
    }
    if completedArray.count == 0 {
        allComplete()
    }
    else {
        tasksIncomplete()
        tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
    }       
}
tableView.endUpdates()
```

The functions `allComplete()` and `tasksIncomplete()` just hide and show the tableView when there is no data to view or when new data is added. My code to complete a task is as follows:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.completedArray.append(thisTask)
self.taskArray[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
if self.taskArray[indexPath.section] == [] {
    self.taskArray.remove(at: indexPath.section)
    self.dynamicSectionHeaders.remove(at: indexPath.section)
    self.tableView.deleteSections([indexPath.section], with: .left)
}
else {
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

And the code to mark a task incomplete is:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.completedArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
if self.completedArray.count == 0 {
    self.tableView.deleteSections([0], with: .left)
}
else {
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
self.sortIncompleteTaskArray()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

The `taskArray` is a two dimensional array containing sections and then the actual data. The `completedArray` is just one dimensional. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked all over and it seems this error has never been documented. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by manually reloading my entire data source when the complete button is pressed. It may not be the best solution but it works.